# call wcf service by form submit

Tags: wcf, forms

I have service

```
[OperationContract]
void AddData(str ingdata)
```

implementation

```
void AddData(string data)
{
 NameValueCollection dataToAdd= HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data);
 //do seomething with data
}
```

and html form

```
<form action='service.com/Service.svc/AddData' method="post" target="_blank">
    <label >FirstName</label>
    <input  type="text" size="30" name="FirstName">
    <label >LastName</label>
    <input  type="text" size="30" name="LastName">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have big problem to invoke this service. Always after submit I was redirect to service url, but breakpoint on service implementation never fire :/ 
I want to after submit collect all data from text input and get it in service parameter..

Do I something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When call wcf service from html form is the best to use Stream type as parameter in service method

```
[OperationContract]
void AddData(Stream data)
```

In stream I have all parameters send from html controls in form and them could me get using that code:

```
NameValueCollection PostParameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd());
```

This solve my problem